# src script only works on home page?

Tags: php

Okay, so when I include my header in any page besides the home page, and I inspect the page, all of the calls show as errors because it's adding that page to the root of the source call. How do I change that?? Here are some of my calls:

```
<script src="wp-content/themes/gamer_meld/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="wp-content/themes/gamer_meld/js/fancySelect.js"></script>
<script src="wp-content/themes/gamer_meld/js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't put script tags directly in template files, enqueue them from your theme/child theme's `functions.php`. Second, use the API to output URIs for scripts, don't hardcode or use relative paths.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'flexslider',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'fancyselect',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancySelect.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myscript',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2):

While everything @milo says is true, your core problem is cuased by you using relative urls. Never ever use relative urls as you never know where they are going to point to in different pages

Comment: Except when the superior requires from you to use relative URLs or you are fired. :) Or, you cannot resist the inertia.